# Develop or Plugin suggestion for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a WP site which will have a single membership. Each member will have its own page where the posts added by that user will be displayed. I know Wordpress comes with the default author and posts, but it does allow only premium members to add posts and paid registration/profile. Shall I develop a custom one or there is any available plugin. I tried, but did not find any similar to my requirement.

Any suggestion and help will be much appreciated...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very flexible plugin that allows you to create/configure members stuff [Ultimate Member](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/).

Check [How to customize member templates](https://suiteplugins.com/customize-ultimate-member-templates/), [Code Examples](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/category/48-code-examples), and other [documentation](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/).